# How can i ignore a character at start/end of the match, i am like tryin to find command-line arguments

Tags: c#, regex

So what i want is to split a space seprated string/line/text, little bit like command-line args.
Lets say i have this

```
command argument0 'argument1' 'argument2, the whitespaces will be ignored'
```

The pattern i tried:

```
/('[^']*')|([!-&(-~]+)/g
```

It matches those: `command` `argument0` `'argument1'` `'argument2, the whitespaces will be ignored'`

Its working like i excepected, but i am wondering if there is a way to not include `'`.                                     If you know how to do it if it's possible explain it. and sorry if the question is not clear its my first time here

Edit : this pattern close to the solution `([^'] [^']*[^'])|([!-&(-~]+)`

Comment: Exclude them from the capturing group, `/'([^']*)'|([!-&(-~]+)/g`

Comment: `([^'] [^']*[^'])|([!-&(-~]+)` is not a solution. The solution is above. What is your programming language?

Comment: Using System.Text.RegularExpression in c# + yeah i figured this out, but it was close to solution

Comment: Aha, so you used `Regex.Matches(text, @"'([^']*)'|([!-&(-~]+)").Cast<Match>().Select(x => $"x.Groups[1].Value}{x.Groups[2].Value}")`?

Comment: I am right now testing it on https://regexr.com, i use `Regex.Split( text,  myPattern );` it should return me string[] and thats all i need

Comment: Why do you test a regex that you need to use in C#, .NET, in a non-NET regex tester? Why use `Regex.Split`? You have a  matching regex.

Comment: Alright i will give it a try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should move the first pair of parentheses to exclude both `'` chars and use

```
'([^']*)'|([!-&(-~]+)
```

See the [C# demo](https://ideone.com/84qoxV):

```cs
string text = "command argument0 'argument1' 'argument2, the whitespaces will be ignored'";
string[] results = Regex.Matches(text, @"'([^']*)'|([!-&(-~]+)")
        .Cast<Match>()
        .Select(x => $"{x.Groups[1].Value}{x.Groups[2].Value}")
        .ToArray();
Console.WriteLine(string.Join("\n", results));
```

Output:

```
command
argument0
argument1
argument2, the whitespaces will be ignored
```

Comment: Wow, that works but how .NET and regexr.com are diffrents?

Comment: regexr.com supports JavaScript and PCRE regex libraries. C# uses a .NET regex library, that works differently in some cases, and supports some features JS and PCRE do not.